# Java async api call - fire and forget http call

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a java spring boot api(data receptor) which aclient calls for persisting some data. Once I finish persisting the data I want to make another api call (which is supposed to process the persisted data - data aggregater) and it should run asynchronously on its own and the original program should terminate after simply calling the data aggregater. I do not want the data receptor to wait for the data aggregator to finish before it can finish. It needs to be a type of fire and forget api call to a http url. Can you suggest on how to go about it?

Comment: Use Spring-boot's `@Async` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 've arrived at the below solution based on above suggestions and [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

Public Async Method in its own class

```
@Service
public class CallAggrAsync 
{
    @Async
    public void fireandforgetrag()
    {
        try
        {
            URL myurl = new URL("http://myurl.com");
            URLConnection myconn = myurl.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                myconn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error firing or forgetting: "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Application.java where we switch on EnableAsync

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application
{
    public static void main(final String args[]) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor asyncExecutor() 
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

I call the above async method

```
@Service
public class Persist
{

    @Autowired private CallAggrAsync asy;
    public boolean somefunc()
    {
        //do some work  
        asy.fireandforgetrag("server",hostname);
        //do some more work which will continue running without waiting for above 
        function to finish
     }
 }
```